# Positioning to bottom-right in an absoluteLayout in xamarin.android

Tags: xaml, android-layout, xamarin.android

I have an absolute layout like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AbsoluteLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
       //stuff
    </LinearLayout>
    <Button
        android:text="test"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_x="10dp"
        android:layout_y="10dp"
         />
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

It takes a button and positions it to a top left position at 10dp from top of the screen and 10dp from the left of the screen.

I need to add another button there and position it to the bottom right of the screen, but I do not know how to set the positions (layout_x and y) to be calculated from bottom and right positions, they are currently calculated from the top and left.

Is this possible? I would be even willing to use relative or similar layout, instead of the absolute, if it would solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AbsoluteLayout` is deprecated since API3.

you can use `RelativeLayout` instead and set `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` and `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"` for the Button.

```
    <Button
    android:text="Button"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
```